# Can't get the parameters of a func using threading lib in a python decoration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, args, window-decoration

Below is the python codes,The decoration is ok without thread created through a class inherit from threading.thread. for example create a thread by giving the target func as a paremeter to threading.thread()

```
import threading ,time
from time import sleep, ctime
import functools

def find(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print("ags:%s,%s\n" % (args,kwargs))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@find
def now() :
    return str( time.strftime( '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' , time.localtime() ) )

class myThread (threading.Thread) :
    """docstring for myThread"""
    @find
    def __init__(self, nloop, nsec) :
        super(myThread, self).__init__()
        self.nloop = nloop
        self.nsec = nsec

    @find
    def run(self):
        print('start loop', self.nloop, 'at:', ctime())
        sleep(self.nsec)
        print('loop', self.nloop, 'done at:', ctime())
@find
def main():
    thpool=[]
    print('starting at:', now())

    for i in range(10):
        thpool.append(myThread(i,2))

    for th in thpool:
        th.start()

    for th in thpool:
        th.join()

    print('all Done at:', now())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I got a error info as below:

```
File "F:\question\multithreadfmclass.py", line 15, in wrapper
    print("ags:%s,%s\n" % (args,kwargs))
  File "D:\ProgramFiles\Python352\lib\threading.py", line 813, in __repr__
    assert self._initialized, "Thread.__init__() was not called"
AssertionError: Thread.__init__() was not called
```

How to remove the bugs? tks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the `Thread` object before it is initialized which is impossible. It is not easy to find this mistake because of your decorator but if you call `func` first, then it works:

```
def find(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("ags:%s,%s\n" % (args, kwargs))
        return result

return wrapper
```